# Prove a matrix has non-zero determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-matrices

While working on a problem, I managed to reduce it to showing that the matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$, where $2a_{ij} = \frac{1}{i+j-1} - \frac{(-1)^{i+j-1}}{i+j-1}$, has non-zero determinant, for whatever size you choose. Here are a few cases:
$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} \end{bmatrix} = \frac{4}{135};$$

$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \frac{1}{7} \end{bmatrix} = \frac{16}{23625}$$

I worked on a few cases using online calculators, but explicit determinant calculation in arbitrary sizes is very cumbersome. It seems to tend to $0$, but to always be positive. In fact, I suspect this is a positive-definite matrix, but, again, couldn't quite prove it - and I recall having seen it in a computational setting before, maybe numerical integration, though I'm not sure...

Anyhow, is there any technique I can use to show this has non-zero determinant for any size I pick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Observation: $A$ is symmetric. Although I don't see how that can be used yet

Comment: @fwd Indeed - I even tried to use a diagonalization argument, but that went nowhere...

Comment: Also, why do you have zero entries in your examples?

Comment: @fwd Sorry, forgot to add a term - I'll fix it! EDIT: fixed it (the examples were correct, the definition wasn't)

Comment: It might be a bit of extra algebra, but for the first few cases, use row reduction to diagonalize. You may find a common pattern due to the common structure. This way, you could show all diagonal elements are nonzero and thus $\det(A)=\prod_k \lambda_k$ is nonzero.

Comment: Extra hint/observation: your second example contains a principal submatrix equal to your first example. So I believe you will have a straightforward proof by induction (using also my prior comment).

Comment: @fwd I tried it using Sylvester's criterion, but many cofactors appear other than the sub matrix...

Comment: Have you noticed that your matrix is cousin of [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), known to be the inverse of very quickly growing integers... ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Actually, I hadn’t… I didn’t know this matrix - I’ll see if it leads somewhere, thank you!

Comment: Outline of another solution: $A$ is half the Grammian matrix of the linearly independent vectors $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ in $L^2[-1, 1]$ and is therefore positive definite.  (So, to unfold the standard proof of Grammian matrices being positive definite: for a column vector $b$, $b^T A b = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 (b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_{n-1} x^{n-1})^2\,dx$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Let $C:=(\frac1{i+j-1})_{1\le i,j\le n}$. This is a symmetric matrix known as a [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix). By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), it is positive-definite.
- Let $D$ be the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix whose $i$-th diagonal element is $(-1)^{i-1}$. We can easily check by matrix multiplication that $A=(DCD+C)/2$.
- We observe that $DCD=(D\sqrt C)(D\sqrt C)^T$ where $\det(D\sqrt C)\neq0$, so $DCD$ is also a positive-definite matrix. Hence $A$ is the sum of two positive-definite matrices, and therefore also positive-definite. In particular $\det(A)>0$.

Comment: [+1] for the astute method of solution, but I disagree with the term "Cauchy matrix" for $C$ : it is a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)

Comment: @Jean Marie: you're right, I kind of mixed up the two. A Hilbert matrix is a special case of a Cauchy matrix.

Comment: I agree with the qualification "special case" but it is not worth the value to refer to a Cauchy matrix.