# Determining whether two known vectors are coplanar in a certain plane orthogonal to an unknown vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose you have some vector $a$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $H$ be the hyperplane such that $\Bbb{R}^n=\operatorname{span}\{a\}\oplus H$, so that every vector orthogonal to $a$ lies on this plane.

What is the equation of this plane? Edit: the equation of the plane is in fact trivial. However, I am actually interested in determining whether two vectors lie in this plane - see below.

This came up for me when I gave a (I now believe mistaken) answer on this site, which I have now removed, that stated:

$$a_1\frac{1}{9}+a_2\frac{1}{15}+a_3\frac{1}{21}+\cdots+a_n\frac{1}{6n+3}\neq a_1\frac{1}{5}+a_2\frac{1}{7}+a_3\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+a_n\frac{1}{2n+3}$$

And my rationale at the time was that, considering dot products between $a$ and the vectors formed by the LHS and RHS coefficients (the LHS being clearly smaller in magnitude) could not be the same, but I realised I couldn't prove it and so I removed my answer. This lead me to the thought: if you know $a\cdot b=a\cdot c$, where $b,c$ are known, can you derive $a$? And then I thought, we know $a\cdot(b-c)=0$, and in the question I could actually find another pair such that $a\cdot(d-e)=0$, with again $d,e$ being known, and I pictured the plane around $a$ of all vectors orthogonal to it, looking for a geometric intuition, being frustrated that even though I knew $b-c$ and $d-e$, I could not show that it was impossible for them both to lie on this plane, $H$ - which has now led me to this question. In sum, if $b,c,d,e$ are all known and $a$ is unknown, can you derive $a$ or show the non-existence of $a$ from $a\cdot(b-c)=a\cdot(d-e)=0$? I felt as if being able to find an equation to the plane $H$ would be useful in this, but I couldn't begin to solve this. Edit: again, the plane equation is trivial, but it doesn’t immediately help me to determine if $b-c$ and $d-e$ can both lie on this plane.

The original question I was working on is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233057/815585).

Comment: If you have $n-1$ linearly independent vectors that span the hyperplane, the scalar product of each of them with $a$ is zero. This gives a system of $n-1$ linear equations. From it, $a$ is defined (up to a real non-zero multiple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b = c$ then information gathered from $c$ does not add anything to information gathered from $b,$ so we should exclude that case.
If $b$ and $c$ are parallel and unequal then it is not possible that
$a \cdot b = a \cdot c,$ so we should exclude that case also.

So let's assume $b$ and $c$ are two independent vectors. Neither is a scalar product of the other. This implies that $n \geq 2$ since you cannot have two independent vectors in a one- or zero-dimensional vector space.

Given the known vectors $b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and any scalar constant $m$,
if you know that $a \cdot b = m$ then you know a hyperplane of dimension
$n - 1$ in which $a$ must lie.
Likewise, if you know that $a \cdot c = m$ then you again know a hyperplane
of dimension $n - 1$ in which $a$ must lie.
Since the vectors $b$ and $c$ are independent the hyperplanes are not parallel;
they intersect.
In the case $n = 2$ the hyperplanes are lines and they intersect in a single point, so you know $a.$
But if $n > 2$ the intersection of the hyperplanes has at least one dimension,
and there are infinitely many possible vectors that could be the vector $a.$

If you know that $a \cdot b = a \cdot c$ but do not know what the value of either product is, things are even worse.
Suppose $a = a_1$ is a solution to the system $a \cdot b = a \cdot c = 1.$
Then $a = 2a_1$ is a solution to the system $a \cdot b = a \cdot c = 2.$
But obviously $a = a_1$ is **not** a solution to $a \cdot b = a \cdot c = 2.$
So without knowing which real number $a \cdot b$ is equal to,
you cannot decide whether $a_1$ is a possible value of $a$ and $2a_1$ is not,
or whether $2a_1$ is a possible value of $a$ and $a_1$ is not.
Moreover, there are an infinite number of other possible values of $a \cdot b,$
each giving a different candidate for $a$ that is incompatible with any of the
results for any other value of $a \cdot b.$

---

As pointed out previously in a comment, however, if you know the values
of each of the products
$a \cdot b_1,$ $a \cdot b_2, \ldots,$ $a \cdot b_n$
for a linearly independent set of vectors
$b_1, \ldots, b_n,$
then you have enough information to identify the vector $a.$
This is essentially a way of using $n$ coordinates
(not necessarily rectangular or equal-scaled) to uniquely describe
every vector in the vector space $\mathbb R^n.$

Answer (score 0):

The equation is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i=0$$
aka all vectors $x$ whose inner product with $a$ is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that is technically a plane equation. I was looking for something to assist me with the rest of my question